# What is "signpost_reporter"?

Tags: macos, mojave, software-update, console

Today I updated my 2014 MacBook Air to macOS Mojave 10.14.5 as it just released. After the update finished, I checked console logs and noticed in 'System Reports' there's a log named "signpost_reporter[date & details].cpu_resource".

In the console log the path is `/usr/libexec/signpost_reporter`, a path i've never seen before until today.

I also updated my family's iMac to 10.14.5 but no signpost_reporter log was created after the instillation finished.

What exactly is "signpost_reporter"? What is it's function?  Why did I get a log for it?

Answer (score 18):

Signposts is a developer feature created by Apple to help developers diagnose performance problems in applications.

Essentially developer can create a “signpost” marking the beginning and end of performance critical operations. The signpost system then automatically times these intervals and makes them available to profiling tools on the local machine.

The signpost_reporter program is used to report these timings back to Apple. I.e. it allows Apple to monitor performance on non-developer machines by sending the telemetry data from the signpost feature to Apple. For example Apple might be interested in knowing how often customers experience problems with a specific feature being too slow.

Without seeing the actual log entry, it’s not possible to say why you got a log entry for it. However rest assured that your system works just as well with and without the signpost_reporter.

Comment: would it be possible for Apple to take a look at it for more information? i would like to know what may have triggered it

Comment: Yes, sure it is possible for them - but I doubt you would have any luck with that. Why are you reluctant to just posting the message here, so that others can help you?

Comment: How do you turn it off? I don't want it wasting a whole core forever.

Comment: It sounds like you have some sort of problem with your Mac. signpost_reporter does not use a whole core in a normal setting. I would advise you to open a new question about that. But in essence you can just stop (i.e. kill) the process like any other program, if it has run amok.

Comment: The more you learn, the more you find out that Apple has your back `all the time`.  Incredible invasion of privacy.

Comment: @gone Why do you think it is an invasion of privacy? - You're asked in advance whether or not you want to participate in sending back analytics to Apple. The signport_reporter reports only internal timing information such as "initializing UIView took 3 milliseconds".

Comment: @jksoegaard:  I'm not sure you get an opportunity to choose in each case this is used.

Comment: Not in each case, but you get to say yes or no in general. If you say no, it’s not transferred.

Comment: Maybe that's true... I generally don't allow telemetry and have my computer locked down pretty well with stuff like opting out of everything and connection monitors and updates made manual on most apps etc. etc. However, I just had it runaway and take 10-99% CPU power for over 5 minutes... which led me to look into it... had to kill it with activity monitor. Searching console I only found the "Spawning" log and the "killing log", couldn't really find anything useful...

Comment: It’s not “maybe true”, it is true. Too bad that you suffered from a bug and had to spend a few minutes closing the program and checking logs. No one wants bugs, but they are there in every complex system. However that doesn’t mean that your privacy was at stake.

Answer (score 7):

The [manual page for signpost_reporter](http://www.manpagez.com/man/8/signpost_reporter/) states:

> ### NAME
>
> `signpost_reporter` -- Report telemetry on intervals instrumented with
>        os_signpost to Apple
>
> ### SYNOPSIS
>
> **signpost_reporter should not be invoked directly**
>
> ### DESCRIPTION
>
> `signpost_reporter` is responsible for periodically gathering and reporting  telemetry about operations instrumented with [`os_signpost`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/os/3019241-os_signpost).

`os_signpost` is a function in macOS for instrumenting specific portions of code:

> Marks a point of interest in your code as a time interval or as an event for debugging performance in Instruments.

You can learn more about the logging service of macOS in Apple's developer documentation, [Logging](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/os/logging).

Answer (score 0):

Short answer to the implied question "can you disable this reporting?": there appears to be no way to disable this usage of signpost

Signpost is part of the Apple sdk and allows developers to use this telemetry without any approval by the user. It is likely used by core Apple services and apps as well as third parties. It is not opted in performance and bug reporting as others have suggested here.

And despite that others seem to be trying to convince otherwise, you would right to be concerned about any telemetry that has not be opted into.

Without assurances with the requisite proof, privacy is definitely at-stake. Just because Apple says 'trust me' doesn't mean privacy is not at stake. There are no guarantees without proof that opting in to 'performance reporting' doesn't enable 'usage reporting' for example: information about sites and content or any amount of data that meet a reasonable standard of expected-to-be-private.

It's also possible that the signpost process could be exploited by malware

I've never been 'asked in advance' signpost, per se. And I have all Analytics sharing options turned off in Prefs, never opted-in to crash or performance reporting, and still have a signpost_report process occasionallyrunning, which sometimes consumes 90% of a core.

Answer (score 0):

**sudo kill -9 *pid_of_the_process***

does the trick of killing it

Comment: Some people's standard answer to a process they don't understand. Kill it.